# Training with a class imbalanced dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a dataset with 50 positive and 950 negative classes. I used Logistic regression with SMOTE and I got an AUC of 69% using 10 fold cross validation. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Even after rectification of class imbalance and N-fold CV if the performance is unsatisfactory probably, the model has reached its limits of explanatory power. Maybe you could try different/additional predictors. Do remember the quote 'If you torture the data long enough, it will confess.', Ronald H. Coase

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended question. There is a helpful chapter in the book Applied Predictive Modeling by Kuhn and Johnson that also shows R code. If you have access to a research library that might help. The authors also have a discussion here: http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/2/1/lw6har9oewknvus176q4o41alqw2ow.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using a bias term, regularizing, and setting the regularization parameter using a validation set, you should do those things.  Beyond that you're entering the thicket of model selection and feature engineering.